# nodemailer - anchor tag not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, gmail, nodemailer

Whenever I try to send an email with an anchor tag using nodemailer v1.10, there is a `3D` character mixed up in my email. I believe this is `%3D` which stands for `=` when decoded. I use gmail as the service for the SMTP transport.

Here is the "html" value I use in nodemailer

```
var resetUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + ':' + req.app.get('port') + '/password/reset?token=' + encodeURIComponent(digest);
options.html = 'To reset your password, click this <a href="' + resetUrl + '"><span>link</span></a>.<br>This is a <b>test</b> email.'
```

Here's how it looks when I click "show original" from the email I received.

```
To reset your password, click this <a href=3D"http://192.168.1.=
109:3000:3000/password/reset?token=3DoU5J1vm4VTLl0Ru8SMI7x3YvF3Y%3D"><span>=
link</span></a>.<br>This is a <b>test</b> email.
```

I also noticed that there are `=` at the end of each line. Is this normal for gmail? The email I receive does appear normal in gmail. The link has a blue font color and is underlined but it does not work when I click it. I tried it in yahoo mail too and the link didn't work also.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the quotes from `"` to `'` used in the anchor tag

Before:

```
options.html = 'To reset your password, click this <a href="' + resetUrl + '"><span>link</span></a>.<br>This is a <b>test</b> email.'
```

After:

```
options.html = "To reset your password, click this <a href='" + resetUrl + "'><span>link</span></a>.<br>This is a <b>test</b> email."
```

Comment: I've found it is always better to have doublequotes inside single quotes and never the other way.